# What is the proper way to manage creation of post with image in Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

When a user makes a new post I need to upload an image to Storage, retrieve the uploaded image URL and make multiple Realtime Database writes with post data to the user and his followers timelines.

I know about multi-path batch updates, but how do I make sure this batch updates will occur in the first place? What if the user's internet connection interrupts right after file upload, now there's a file in storage taking up space but no post-entries in database. How do I tackle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What if the user's internet connection interrupts right after file upload, now there's a file in storage taking up space but no post-entries in database.

You won't be able to handle this very well using frontend code only. There is nothing stopping a client from app from disappearing after an upload but before a record of that is made in your database.

What you should do is use a [Cloud Storage trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events) to make sure some backend code runs reliably after the upload completes.  You will need to make sure your database data matches that of you file upload path so the two pieces of data can be located together.

I will point out that this is really not easy to manage, and will require a fair amount of design and hundreds of lines of code between both your frontend and backend to get it to work reliably. A full discussion is too much for a single Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: Thank you for an answer! Guess I'll stick to frontend only because it's too much of a work for portfolio project which won't be used.